# Metodos do managedBean não são processados

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Bom dia, estou o seguinte problema. tenho uma aplicação que tem vários ManagedBeans que estão funcionando normalmente.
Hoje fui criar um novo bean pra fazer um testes e este *bean não executa* nem o *@PostConstruct* e nem qualquer outro método;
Eu criei um novo projeto, copiei o bean e o xhtml e no novo projeto funcionou, mas não gostaria de recriar tudo novamente. ou ainda, gostaria de saber o que houve.

*Segue o bean :*

```
    package teste;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

    @ManagedBean(name = "testeBean2")
    @ViewScoped
    public class TesteBean2 implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
           System.out.println("aqui estou dentro do bean   ");
        }

        public String getMensagem() {
             System.out.println("chegou aqui ");
             return "bada bada";
        }
    }
```

*Segue o teste2.xhtml:*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="aqui #{testeBean2.mensagem}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

***Importante:***

1. Em um novo projeto funciona normal.
2. Estou usando o Eclipse Mars 2 e Tomcat 8
3. Versões são:

   - javax.faces(Mojarra) = 2.2.8-02
   - javax.servlet-api  = 3.1.0
   - primefaces = 5.3
   - primefaces-extensions = 3.2.0

**Perguntas**
1 - É normal de vez em quando ter de criar um novo projeto ?
2 - Porque isso ocorre ?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia pessoal, em partes consegui resolver o problema

Não estava funcionando nem no eclipse nem no NetBeans.

Já havia tentado diversas coisas:

- Projec/Build all
- Project/clean
- remover o projeto do tomcat
- remover o tomcat e instalar novamente

**Nada funcionou !!!**

**O caminho que fiz e que resolveu foi :**

- Verificar se tinha conflito de dependências no pom.xml. E TINHA !!!
- para saber isso abri o pom no eclipse e fui na guia **dependency hierarchy** , ele mostra os que estão em conflito. e fui fazendo downgrade/upgrade das versões de modo a torná-las compatíveis.
  **mesmo assim não funcionou no eclipse**.
- Testei **no NetBeans** e **funcionou** acredito ser algum problema do eclipse

Obrigado pelo apoio e espero que eu tenha ajudado alguém conseguindo resolver o mesmo problema que o meu.

**OBS:** *se você souber como resolver isso no eclipse, por favor comente esse post*